# Disable all sidebar in specific page without editing theme files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Currently I am creating a plugin. The plugin shortcode create a image upload form with various option. What I need is if I paste the plugin shortcode in any page in theme, then that page become fullwidth without any sidebar. 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you get the plugin to initiate the following CSS if the short code exists?

```
aside {
    display: none;
}

main {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for this answer . Let me know what is main and what is aside? Is this present in all wordpress theme by default ?

Comment: <aside> is the element that contains the sidebar.
<main> contains the central content.

As long as the user has not changed these elements in their template is should work fine.

Comment: yes . You are right . Thank you . But could you please tell where you get this information.

Comment: I just had a look at the template page.php

Answer (score 0):

You need use some code if you want Disable all sidebar in a specific page.

you need to know the class or the id of the page first, and add in your css file this:

```
.class-page .sidebar-class {display: none;}
```

or

```
#id-page .sidebar-class {display: none;}
```

You can se the name in your inspector elements in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

When your short code is added into the page at that time one function will be called to display upload image form with various option. In that function include on javascript & css with below code.

1. Javascript code:

   ```
   //Below code will add 'full_width' class to your 'body' tag
     $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(body).addClass('full_width');
    })
   ```
2. Css code:

   ```
    // Display content in full width
    .full_width #layout {
     max-width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     }

      // Hide sidebar component
       .full_width #sidebar {
       display:none;
     }
   ```

Thanks!